# Show result by date that we pick - Play Framework

Tags: java, mysql, date, datetime, playframework-1.x

I have a page that show all lists from "dataLansia" table. Like this one :

http://i61.tinypic.com/fliwcm.jpg

And then, I want to make a little improvement. When I pick a date from that date input and I press 'Cari' button, the page show me only the result from 'dataLansia' table where the attribute of 'Tanggal Data' match with the date I pick before. How to do that ?

Here's my stuff (controller, model, view) :

```html
public class Application extends Controller {
  //the other code


  public static void rekap(){
    List rekapProfil=dataLansia.findAll();
    render(rekapProfil);
  }
}
```

```html
public class dataLansia extends Model{ 
 public String tensi;
 public int guladarah;
 public int kolesterol;
 public double asamurat;
 
 @Unique
 public java.util.Date tglData;
 
 @Lob
 public String keluhan;
 
 @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
 public potensi lans;
 
 @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
 public lansia lansia;
  
}
```

```html
public class lansia extends Model {
 @Unique
 public int idLansia;
 
 public String namaLansia;
 public int umur;
 
 @Lob
 public String alamat;
 
 @OneToMany(mappedBy="lansia",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
 public Collection<dataLansia> dataLansia;
  
 public String toString(){
  return namaLansia;
 } 
}
```

```html
#{extends 'Template/Dashboard.html' /}
#{set title:messages.get('rekap.title') /}


<div class="row">
 
 <input type="date" name="rekapTgl.tglData.format('yyyy-MM-dd')" /> &nbsp; <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Cari" />
  
 <table class="table table-bordered table-striped responsive">
  <thead> 
   <tr>
       <th class="text-center">Tanggal Data</th>
       <th class="text-center">ID Lansia</th>
       <th class="text-center">Nama Lansia</th>
       <th class="text-center">Umur</th>
       <th class="text-center">Alamat</th>
       <th class="text-center">Tensi<br />(mmHg)</th>
       <th class="text-center">Gula Darah<br />(mg/dL)</th>
       <th class="text-center">Kolesterol<br />(mg/dL)</th>
       <th class="text-center">Asam Urat<br />(mg/dL)</th>
       <th class="text-center">Keluhan</th>
       <th class="text-center">Potensi / Tidak Potensi</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
#{list items:rekapProfil, as:'rD'}
   
    <tr>
     <td class="text-center">${rD.tglData.format('dd-MM-yyyy')}</td>
     <td class="text-center">${rD.lansia.idLansia}</td> 
        <td class="text-center">${rD.lansia.namaLansia}</td>
        <td class="text-center">${rD.lansia.umur}</td>
        <td class="text-center">${rD.lansia.alamat}</td>
        <td class="text-center">${rD.tensi}</td>
        <td class="text-center">${rD.guladarah}</td>
        <td class="text-center">${rD.kolesterol}</td>
        <td class="text-center">${rD.asamurat}</td>
        <td class="text-center">${rD.keluhan}</td>
        <td class="text-center">${rD.lans.namaPotensi}</td>
    </tr>
#{/list}

  </tbody>
 </table>
 
 #{else}
  <br /><center><b><i>Belum ada lansia terimunisasi.</i></b></center>
 #{/else}
</div>
```